# JavaScript backbone collection sort on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have data like

```
-------------------------
id | name | parentId
-------------------------
1  | a    |
2  | z    |
3  | b    |
4  | z1   | 2
5  | y2   | 1
6  | y1   | 1
7  | y3   | 1
-------------------------
```

in backbone collection.

**I want to sort on the field name but child object should be placed just below parent(*based on parentId*),** 
i.e.

```
-------------------------
id | name | parentId
-------------------------
1  | a    |
6  | y1   | 1
5  | y2   | 1
7  | y3   | 1
3  | b    |
2  | z    |
4  | z1   | 2
-------------------------
```

Here y1, y2 and y3 is up because they are child of a(id 1).

I am using backbone collection comparator.
(But comparator in just javasript will do to - I will converto to backbone comparator).

Answer (score 5):

```
var comparator = function(a, b) {
    var aName = a.get('name'), 
        bName = b.get('name'),
        aParentId = a.get('parentId'),
        bParentId = b.get('parentId');

    if(!aParentId || !bParentId || aParentId == bParentId) {
         // In these 3 cases, name has precedence

        if(aName < bName) {
            return -1;
        } 
        else if(aName > bName) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }

    } else if(aParentId < bParentId) {
        return -1;
    } else /* aParentId > bParentId */ {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

EDIT: Corrected. The two sorting levels have to be taken into account, keeping in mind that any missing parentId amounts to equal parentIds.

You could also implement it as a list of fields / tailored comparators that execute one after the others, where the next comparator is delegated to when the current finds an equality.

```
var loopedComparator = function(a, b) {
  var fields = [
    {
      name: 'parentId', 
      comparator: function(a, b) {
        return (!a || !b || a == b) ? 0 : (a < b) ? -1 : 1;
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'name',
      comparator: function(a, b) {
        return (a == b) ? 0 : (a < b) ? -1 : 1;
      }
    }
  ];

  var i, result = 0;
  for(i in fields) {
    var field = fields[i];
    result = field.comparator(a.get(field.name), b.get(field.name));
    if(result !== 0) {
      return result; // On inequality we return right away
    }
    // Else we continue, delegating the comparison to the next field / comparator
  }

  // When the loop is done, or if fields was defined empty, we return the last equality
  return result;

};
```

Of course with this scheme you can add as many columns as you like and define custom comparators for each of them.

Comment: Yes this comparator sorts on name, but I want to sort on parent id too,(multiple columns).
Please see my edited question that would clear the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Akshay Corrected. I tried to elaborate on the prev answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanx for the help, but i created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7R3fv/ , from your answer but still not getting the desired result.
Thinking of doing it manually.

Comment: I'm sorry I completely misunderstood your question. You have to build a tree and then walk it depth-first.

Comment: Yes now I am sorting every elements then fetching parent out the looping through parent and adding if any child found. But these seems somewhat complex.